# python flask responds correctly to fetch function in node.js but gives a bad request from chrome console or website javascript

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, flask, fetch

Why this javascript code works in node.js but not in chrome ?

By the way, `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"prompt":"testprompt"}' 192.168.122.234:3000/test` also works.

Error in chrome is not related to cross origin :

```
VM10:4  POST http://192.168.122.234:3000/test net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

This is flasktest.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=('GET', 'POST',))
def testfn():
    # GET request
    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = {'greeting':'Hello from Flask!'}
        return jsonify(message)  # serialize and use JSON headers
    # POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.get_json())  # parse as JSON
            

return 'Sucesss', 200
```

This is javascript code:

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin,>
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
    return response; // response.json() ??? parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

postData('http://192.168.122.234:3000/test', {prompt: "hello" })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not give cors error on chrome browser issue is found to be related to cors.

```
pip3 install flask_cors
```

adding it to server code resolves the issue :

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/test', methods=('GET', 'POST',))
def testfn():
    # GET request
    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = {'greeting':'Hello from Flask!'}
        return jsonify(message)  # serialize and use JSON headers
    # POST request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.get_json())  # parse as JSON
        return 'Sucesss', 200
```

Also we need to change mode: "no-cors" to "cors" in javascript.
But the lack of browser error is misleading ... So instead of deleting the question I decided to answer it.